# derivative of normalized associated Legendre function at the limits of x = +/-1

Tags: legendre-functions

I'm trying to compute the derivative of the normalized associated Legendre function of $x=\cos \theta$ and I'm having issues when $\cos \theta =\pm 1$ which causes the denominator to go to $0$.  I've seen an answer on the forum about the derivative of the associated Legendre polynomial at the boundary of $x=\pm 1$ but I'm looking for the derivative of the normalized associated Legendre function.  The answer is $0$ for all $m$ except for $m=1$ so I was hoping to find a closed form expression in a textbook showing the expression for the special case but I have not found much about the derivative of the normalized associated Legendre function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this worked out.  Below is the answer for anyone else that needs it.

[Expression for theta = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqT5y.png)

[Expression for theta = pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9teG.png)