# First derivative of the associated Legendre function at x=1

Tags: legendre-functions

I'm trying to find the first derivative of the associated Legendre function at $x=1$.
The form I have for the first derivative is divergent at x=1:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d P_l^m(x)}{d \theta}=\frac{l x P_l^m(x)-(l+m) P_{l-1}^m(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{equation}
I know that for any order $l$, the first derivative at $x=1$ is zero for all degrees $m$ except for $m=1$ or $m=-1$ as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqT5y.png by @brad14 in this question
[derivative of normalized associated Legendre function at the limits of x = +/-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369949/derivative-of-normalized-associated-legendre-function-at-the-limits-of-x-1)

but I couldn't derive it. Would anyone help me with that, please?